# How to convert CURL request to Swift using Alamofire?

Tags: swift, curl, alamofire

I am using Alamofire and I have a curl command like this:

```
curl "https://abc.mywebsite.com/obp/v3.1.0/my/page/accounts/myaccount1/account" -H 'Authorization: DirectLogin token="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6wkpeVeCJr.eyIiOiIifQ.MV-E150zMCrk6VrWv"' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

This command works fine on command line and I receive a response successfully.

For Swift I have found very little help online which didn't work for me, and so posting a question here, how can I make this call using Swift?

Ideally I would like to use Alamofire since that's what I use for all my network calls.

I have something like this but it doesn't work, it give User Unauthorized error, which means that it is connecting to the server but not sending the parameters correctly.

```
let url = "https://abc.mywebsite.com/obp/v3.1.0/my/page/accounts/myaccount1/account"
let loginToken = "'Authorization' => 'DirectLogin token=\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6wkpeVeCJr.eyIiOiIifQ.MV-E150zMCrk6VrWv\"', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'"


@IBAction func callAPIAction(_ sender: Any) {
    Alamofire
        .request(
            self.url,
            parameters: [
                "token" : self.loginToken
            ]
        )
        .responseString {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("from .success \(value)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to set header `Authorization` to `DirectLogin token="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6wkpeVeCJr.eyIiOiIifQ.MV-E150zMCrk6VrWv"`. You can do that like this:

```
let loginToken = "DirectLogin token=\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6wkpeVeCJr.eyIiOiIifQ.MV-E150zMCrk6VrWv\""

...

@IBAction func callAPIAction(_ sender: Any) {
    Alamofire
        .request(
            self.url,
            headers: [
                "Authorization": self.loginToken,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            ]
        )
        .responseString {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("from .success \(value)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    } 
}

...
```

Comment: thanks for quick response and yes, that's what I was trying to do but incorrectly. Now it works fine.